# Why is Hyper-V crashing on enhanced session mode?

Tags: windows, windows-10, crash, hyper-v

I'm running a Windows 10 Enterprise build 1607 guest on my Windows 10 Pro build 1607 host machine. I'm not doing it for any useful purpose; just so I can mess around with some Windows settings without doing harm to my host machine.

However, if I use Enhanced Session Mode, VMConnect.exe will inevitably crash. This generally happens when browsing Chrome, or pretty much doing anything else on the VM. When it crashes, the VM still runs and I can connect to it. However, it'll likely crash if I continue to use it on Enhanced Session Mode. Regular session mode works fine, and I would use it to avoid this crashing, but I can never get the screen resolution right.

Any ideas as to identify the culprit? I'll attach an EventViewer log, but I don't know how far that'll go. Probably better, I attached a dump file as well, [here](https://1drv.ms/f/s!Amcrnem8kgXSqGgIZ35LM05Xrxxr).

```
Fault bucket 120518593951, type 4
Event Name: APPCRASH
Response: Not available
Cab Id: 0

Problem signature:
P1: VmConnect.exe
P2: 10.0.14393.0
P3: 5789927d
P4: vorbis.acm
P5: 0.0.3.6
P6: 50a51541
P7: c0000005
P8: 0000000000001f4f
P9: 
P10: 

Attached files:
\\?\C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\WER\Temp\WER59E9.tmp.WERInternalMetadata.xml

These files may be available here:
C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\WER\ReportArchive\AppCrash_VmConnect.exe_a710c4e7c33d15632e3384117f5d943d8267b15_897d8fab_3ef37c85

Analysis symbol: 
Rechecking for solution: 0
Report Id: 491133ab-3810-4e51-ac9c-51d50a0648ef
Report Status: 0
Hashed bucket: 551af8629b4156e1f7fc17e3caa9b110
```

And this:

```
Application: VmConnect.exe
Framework Version: v4.0.30319
Description: The process was terminated due to an unhandled exception.
Exception Info: exception code c0000005, exception address 00007FF9581D1F4F
```

And this:

```
Faulting application name: VmConnect.exe, version: 10.0.14393.0, time stamp: 0x5789927d
Faulting module name: vorbis.acm, version: 0.0.3.6, time stamp: 0x50a51541
Exception code: 0xc0000005
Fault offset: 0x0000000000001f4f
Faulting process id: 0x3c94
Faulting application start time: 0x01d23724161b8726
Faulting application path: C:\WINDOWS\system32\VmConnect.exe
Faulting module path: C:\WINDOWS\system32\vorbis.acm
Report Id: e58a5254-1ec9-4332-bb5a-748dd4829603
Faulting package full name: 
Faulting package-relative application ID:
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The audio codec `vorbis.acm` causes the crash:

```
Faulting module name: vorbis.acm, version: 0.0.3.6, time stamp: 0x50a51541
```

update or remove the software that uses/install `vorbis.acm`.

Comment: That makes sense. It crashes whenever audio tries to play.

Comment: ok, update or remove the codec and look what happens

Comment: Thanks, it worked. The codec was from FL Studio, and since I don't use it anymore I uninstalled it and deleted the codec file. I did some research and another person was having the same problem.